# Conjugate prior Gamma distribution on Poisson intensity

Tags: probability-distributions

I don't know what I am missing in following in my understanding. Whether it is my mathematica code that is incorrect or my mathematical skill is short.

**Gamma distribution is the [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution) when the likelihood function is Poisson distribution.** By this, I understood the following:

$$\overbrace{f(x|y)}^{\rm Gamma(\alpha+x, \beta + 1)}=\frac{\overbrace{f(y|x)}^{\rm Poisson(\lambda)} \cdot \overbrace{f(x)}^{\rm Gamma(\alpha, \beta)}}{\underbrace{f(y)}_{NB(\alpha, \frac{1}{1+\beta}\:)}} $$

If my understanding above is correct then why the LHS is not equal to RHS in following Mathematica code ?

```
Remove["Global`*"]
    f = FullSimplify[(PDF[PoissonDistribution[y], 
          x])*(PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], y])/(PDF[
           NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, 1/(1 + b)], x])];
    g = PDF[GammaDistribution[a + x, (b + 1)], y];
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    x = 5;
    Plot[{f, g}, {y, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

**Correction on Wikipedia page** [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution)

$$\overbrace{f(\lambda|x)}^{\text{Gamma}(k+x,\frac{\theta}{\theta + 1})}=\frac{\overbrace{f(x|\lambda)}^{\text{Poisson}(\lambda)} \cdot \overbrace{f(\lambda)}^{\text{Gamma}(k, \theta)}}{\underbrace{f(y)}_{\text{NB}(k, \frac{1}{1+\theta}\:)}} $$

and

$$\overbrace{f(\lambda|x)}^{\text{Gamma}(\alpha+x,\beta+1)}=\frac{\overbrace{f(x|\lambda)}^{\text{Poisson}(\lambda)} \cdot \overbrace{f(\lambda)}^{\text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)}}{\underbrace{f(y)}_{\text{NB}(\alpha, \frac{\beta}{\beta +1}\:)}} $$

i.e. the two Negative Binomial distributions are mistakenly swapped on wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the correct result because you have two problems:  first, you need to be clear about what type of parametrization you are using for the gamma distribution.  Specifically, if the parametrization is shape $\alpha$ and **rate** $\beta$, then the gamma density is $$f_X(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}.$$  If the parametrization is shape $\alpha$ and **scale** $\beta$, then $$f_X(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x/\beta}}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)}.$$  You should not confuse the two, because in each case the conjugacy looks different.

The second problem is that your hierarchical model specification is reversed in your *Mathematica* code.  The model is

$$X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta) \\ Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(X).$$  So $X$ is the unobserved prior and $Y$ is the distribution of the observed data.  Then the marginal distribution is $Y \sim \operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(?, ?)$ and the posterior is $X \mid Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(?, ?)$.  So in *Mathematica*, the syntax for a shape-scale parametrization should be:

```
f = FullSimplify[PDF[PoissonDistribution[x], y]
        PDF[GammaDistribution[a, b], x] /
        PDF[NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, 1/(1+b)], y],
        {x > 0, y >= 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
g = FullSimplify[PDF[GammaDistribution[a + y, b/(1+b)], x],
        {x > 0, y >= 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
```

And then `f/g` should evaluate to `1` symbolically.   Note the two errors:  first, you've mixed up `x` and `y` in various places in your code, and second, because *Mathematica* consistently uses the shape-scale parametrization, the posterior scale hyperparameter is not $1 + \beta$ but rather $\beta/(1 + \beta)$.  In other words, you are using inconsistent parametrizations on each side of your equation; on the left, a shape-rate gamma, and on the right, a shape-scale gamma.

The same code in a shape-rate parametrization would look like this:

```
f = FullSimplify[PDF[PoissonDistribution[x], y]
        PDF[GammaDistribution[a, 1/b], x] /
        PDF[NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, b/(1+b)], y],
        {x > 0, y > 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
g = FullSimplify[PDF[GammaDistribution[a + y, 1/(1+b)], x],
        {x > 0, y > 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
```

in which case, the posterior rate hyperparameter is $1 + \beta$ as you claim on the LHS of your equation, but then the negative binomial parametrization needs to be adjusted.  Specifically, when we say $Y \sim \operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(r, p)$, we could mean
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \binom{y + r - 1}{r - 1} p^r (1-p)^y, \quad y \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\},$$ **or** we could mean
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \binom{y + r - 1}{r - 1} (1-p)^r p^y, \quad y \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}.$$  *Mathematica* uses the **first** one.  If however you use the second one, then the formula you wrote becomes consistent in parametrizations and $\beta$ is a rate parameter.

This is why it is important to:

1. Always specify the parametrization by stating explicitly the density and mass functions for the model when there is any possibility of ambiguity.
2. Check the documentation for *Mathematica* to see what parametrization is used for the built-in functions.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: I feel that there is a mistake in wiki page. Because ParameterMixtureDistribution[PoissonDistribution[y], 
 y \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[a, b]]  is equal to NegativeBinomialDistribution[a, 1/(1 +b)]. This is swapped on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_discrete_distribution